# How may i fill a 3d array in R?

Tags: r

I have a 3d array as below:

```
prob = array(0,c(7,7,7))
```

Now, i need to refill it by random numbers as below:

```
pop = sample(1:100, 7**3, replace=TRUE)
pop = pop/sum(pop)
```

if simply assign the value to it then it will remove all the dimentions of `prob` :

```
prob = pop

print(dim(prob))
```

The output of the print is:

```
> print(dim(prob))
NULL
```

Therefore, apparently the `prob = pop` erase the dimensions.

**How can i assign data but keep the 3d dimensions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform subset assignment as follows:

```
prob[] = pop
```

This will replace the values but preserve dimensions and other attributes.

However, this seems unnecessary in your case: why assign after the fact, when you can initialise?

```
pop = sample(1 : 100, 7 ** 3, replace = TRUE)
prob = array(pop / sum(pop), c(7, 7, 7))
```

There’s no need to pre-assign `prob` as a zero array, and in fact I’d consider that an anti-pattern: in general you should treat variables as read-only, unless there are specific reasons to reassign/modify them (and there rarely are).